# Propel and Collection Methods

Tags: php, orm, propel2

I am developing a PHP app with Propel ORM as a model. It's installed via Composer and all classes are auto-loaded correctly. I can create querys, access database and retrieve data to populate my page. Nice.

But I'm having trouble with some methods like `isLast()`. According to [documentation](http://propelorm.org/documentation/reference/model-criteria.html#collection-methods), you can use it as follows:

```
$books = BookQuery::create()->find();
foreach ($books as $book){
  if($books->isLast()){
    // Do something
  }
}
```

I can't even replicate this simple example. I have simplified my code in order to see if it works (with my own tables and columns names):

```
$provincias=ProvinciasQuery::create()->find();
foreach($provincias as $v){
  echo $v->getProvinciasNombre(); // This works!
  if($provincias->isLast()){ // This doesn't :(
    // Do something
  }
}
```

I get always the same error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Propel\Runtime\Exception\BadMethodCallException' with message 'Call
>   to undefined method: isLast' in
>   /path/to/my/app/vendor/propel/propel/src/Propel/Runtime/Collection/Collection.php
>   on line 558

Same happens with other methods like `isEven()`, `isOdd()` or `isFirst()`. Method `isEmpty()` seems to work fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/propel-users/jZGvx2p7gEw):

```
$books = BookQuery::create()->find();
$booksLoop = $books->getIterator();
foreach ($booksLoop as $book) {
  if ($booksLoop->isFirst()) echo "First";
}
```

Official documentation for Propel 2 is outdated. I have already filed an issue at github: https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2/issues/1314